# How do I get the datatable Sort to repeat in a LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a sort routine in my LWC datatable component.  The first time I click the column header, the data is sorted ascending.  The second time I click the header, the data is sorted descending.  Every header click after that does nothing.

testDatatable.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable
            data={mydata}
            columns={columns}
            key-field={keyfield}
            onrowaction={handleRowAction}
            sorted-by={sortedBy}
            sorted-direction={sortedDirection}
            onsort={updateColumnSorting}>
    </lightning-datatable>     
</template>
```

testDatatable.js

```
import { LightningElement, api, track  } from 'lwc';

const COLUMNS = [
    {
        label: 'Name',
        fieldName: 'Name',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: 'true',
        initialWidth: 280
    },
    {
        label: 'Button',
        type: 'button',
        typeAttributes: { 
            label: 'Select',
            name: 'select',
            title: 'Click to do something',
            disabled: { fieldName: 'buttonDisabled' },
        },
        initialWidth: 90
    },
];

const MYDATA = [
    {
        Name: '',
        Id: '',
        buttonDisabled: ''
    }
];
export default class TestDatatable extends LightningElement {

    @api tableData;
    @api columns = COLUMNS;
    @api keyfield = 'Id';
    @track sortedBy;
    @track SortedDirection;
    @track mydata = MYDATA;

    connectedCallback() {
        // Add fields to datatable records
        console.log('Table',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.tableData)));
        console.log('My',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.mydata)));
        this.mydata = this.tableData.map(tableRecord => ({
            Id: tableRecord.Id,
            Name: tableRecord.Name,
            buttonDisabled: false
            })
        );
        console.log('My-after',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.mydata)));
    }

    handleRowAction(event) {
        const action = event.detail.action;
        const row = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail.row));
        const keyValue = row[this.keyfield];   
        console.log('Action,Key,Row',action.name,keyValue,row);
        // Change the label and disable the button here
        this.mydata = this.mydata.map(rowData => {
            if (rowData[this.keyfield] === keyValue) {
                switch (action.name) {
                    case 'select':
                        console.log('select',rowData[this.keyfield],rowData['select']);
                        rowData.buttonDisabled = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                }                
            }
            return rowData;
        });
    }

    updateColumnSorting(event) {
        this.sortedBy = event.detail.fieldName;
        this.SortedDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
        this.sortData(this.sortedBy, this.SortedDirection);
    }

    sortData(fieldname, direction) {
        // serialize the data before calling sort function
        let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.mydata));

        // Return the value stored in the field
        let keyValue = (a) => {
            return a[fieldname];
        };

        // checking reverse direction 
        let isReverse = direction === 'asc' ? 1: -1;

        // sorting data 
        parseData.sort((x, y) => {
            x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : ''; // handling null values
            y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';

            // sorting values based on direction
            return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
        });

        // set the sorted data to data table data
        this.mydata = parseData;

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you keep doing `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`? That's mostly unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a typo:

```
sorted-direction={sortedDirection}
```

JavaScript is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe, and so is Aura and LWC. As such, it should have been `SortedDirection`, not `sortedDirection`.

I recommend that you always use lowercase/camelCase names for variables, and TitleCase names for classes. Going by this recommendation, the attribute value was fine, but your JavaScript actually has all the typos.

As far as your sort function, it works okay, but could be greatly simplified.

```
updateColumnSorting(event) {
    this.sortedBy = event.detail.fieldName;
    this.sortedDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
    let fieldValue = row => row[this.sortedBy] || '';
    let reverse = this.sortedDirection === 'asc'? 1: -1;
    this.mydata = [...this.mydata.sort(
        (a,b)=>(a=fieldValue(a),b=fieldValue(b),reverse*((a>b)-(b>a)))
    )];
}
```

This is a lot to unpack for such a short amount of code, but here goes.

```
let fieldValue = row => row[this.sortedBy] || '';
```

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) have this nifty property where the return value is assumed to be the expression if there's only one statement. Also, while we're here, the [Logical `||` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) is basically shorthand for (`a? a: ''`); we can use it to say "use the value on the left or the empty string if no value is present".

```
[...value]
```

This is called the "[spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)", and it serves as a shallow-copy function, similar to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))`, but only works on top level items. This is acceptable in this case, since that's all your array should have.

```
(a,b)=>(a=fieldValue(a),b=fieldValue(b),reverse*((a>b)-(b>a)))
```

We have more than one parameter, so we need parentheses here for the parameters. In addition, we use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) to evaluate the "extract field value from a and b", then return the desired result at the end. More parentheses make sure the code executes in the correct order.

Edit:

I've also created a [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/JRnKRaXh/1/edit) for this answer.

Comment: Awesome - Thank You.  I'm learning a bit at a time.  I'll have another question tomorrow about preselected rows in a datatable.